# Shopping for and mounting this type of bathroom sink

Tags: plumbing

I am looking to replace one  of my bathroom sinks at home (the enamel is clearly eroded so I decide to replace it).

I have a few questions:

1. How to shop for one.  Attached is the photo of my bathroom sink that is in better shape - have three bathrooms with the same type of bathroom sink and mounts. The place is 40 years old and I moved in 15 years ago.   I measured the sink width and it shows 16”.
2. Also wanted to share with you how it’s currently mounted - all sinks are mounted on a marble countertop (they’ve seen better days) and wondering if someone could share a link or video of how to mount this type of sink.  I can replace water supply and p-traps and such but never had to replace a sink before.  The mount type looks like it is drop-in but not recessed- and the sink has three holes to mount the faucets and the sink stopper in the middle.

Thank you for your inputs in advance.

[image: bathroom sink mount marble countertop]

Comment: I’d start thinking about getting a new countertop with an integrated sink. (The chances of you finding an exact replacement for the sink only are slim.) Take your counter width/ depth and see if the big box stores or plumbing showrooms have anything. If not, go online, but watch shipping costs on heavy stuff like this.

Comment: That's called an undermount sink. You *might* get lucky and find out the same shape as your cutout.  Remove the faucet and trace the edge of the countertop, then go to a store and see if anything matches.

Comment: Thank you Aloysius and Huesmann.  I am thinking of drop-in sink mounts as an option - hoping that the conversion from u derelict f to drop-in mount type instead.  That would be the only way to be able to save /reuse  my existing countertop.  Looking to replace the other two sinks down the road.   

I see 19-20” drop in sinks online showing the basin size as 16” or so which is close to  my 16” basin size.  So I am cautiously optimistic.